# Why Flutter app does not run on chrome with the command flutter run -d chrome

Tags: flutter, web, dart

I have been working on a project with Flutter and it works on mobile without issue. but when I want to run it on web using the command `flutter run -d chrome` the browser opens with a blank screen. when I inspect the page the console show the following errors.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)       dart_stack_trace_mapper.js:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)       require.js:1
>
> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)       :59034/favicon.ico:1

Comment: Please add more clarity to your question, code, context, details that might help people assist you

Comment: try this link please https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web

Comment: I have followed all those steps in that link. I don't have any issues with that. the problem is when the browser opens nothing shows up

Comment: I was having the same problem as you and running `flutter channel master` as pointed by @anonymous worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Had the same issue, I switched to "master" channel, I supposed there is an issue with "beta" channel

Answer (score 2):

You should change flutter channel to `master`

`flutter channel master`

Then, it will work.

(From this github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/52963)

Comment: not working by changing channel to master